Debuggin MSAL-node
Following this tutorial.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/tutorial-v2-nodejs-webapp-msal
Local implementation of MSAL-node in Express JS works fine but after deploying to remote Widows server it returns error 500 and there is nothing related in the server logs.
Question
MSAL should have its own logger, where can I see its logs?
Express JS route
router.get("/login", (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  // ... some other logic
  aadMsalAuthenticator.login(aadRequest)(req, res, next);
});

Example of MSAL authenticator from the article above
const msal = require('@azure/msal-node');
const axios = require('axios');

const { msalConfig } = require('../authConfig');

class AuthProvider {
    msalConfig;
    cryptoProvider;

    constructor(msalConfig) {
        this.msalConfig = msalConfig
        this.cryptoProvider = new msal.CryptoProvider();
    };

    login(options = {}) {
        return async (req, res, next) => {

            /**
             * MSAL Node library allows you to pass your custom state as state parameter in the Request object.
             * The state parameter can also be used to encode information of the app's state before redirect.
             * You can pass the user's state in the app, such as the page or view they were on, as input to this parameter.
             */
            const state = this.cryptoProvider.base64Encode(
                JSON.stringify({
                    successRedirect: options.successRedirect || '/',
                })
            );

            const authCodeUrlRequestParams = {
                state: state,

                /**
                 * By default, MSAL Node will add OIDC scopes to the auth code url request. For more information, visit:
                 * https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-permissions-and-consent#openid-connect-scopes
                 */
                scopes: options.scopes || [],
                redirectUri: options.redirectUri,
            };

            const authCodeRequestParams = {
                state: state,

                /**
                 * By default, MSAL Node will add OIDC scopes to the auth code request. For more information, visit:
                 * https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-permissions-and-consent#openid-connect-scopes
                 */
                scopes: options.scopes || [],
                redirectUri: options.redirectUri,
            };

            /**
             * If the current msal configuration does not have cloudDiscoveryMetadata or authorityMetadata, we will 
             * make a request to the relevant endpoints to retrieve the metadata. This allows MSAL to avoid making 
             * metadata discovery calls, thereby improving performance of token acquisition process. For more, see:
             * https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-node/docs/performance.md
             */
            if (!this.msalConfig.auth.cloudDiscoveryMetadata || !this.msalConfig.auth.authorityMetadata) {

                const [cloudDiscoveryMetadata, authorityMetadata] = await Promise.all([
                    this.getCloudDiscoveryMetadata(this.msalConfig.auth.authority),
                    this.getAuthorityMetadata(this.msalConfig.auth.authority)
                ]);

                this.msalConfig.auth.cloudDiscoveryMetadata = JSON.stringify(cloudDiscoveryMetadata);
                this.msalConfig.auth.authorityMetadata = JSON.stringify(authorityMetadata);
            }

            const msalInstance = this.getMsalInstance(this.msalConfig);

            // trigger the first leg of auth code flow
            return this.redirectToAuthCodeUrl(
                authCodeUrlRequestParams,
                authCodeRequestParams,
                msalInstance
            )(req, res, next);
        };
    }

    acquireToken(options = {}) {
        return async (req, res, next) => {
            try {
                const msalInstance = this.getMsalInstance(this.msalConfig);

                /**
                 * If a token cache exists in the session, deserialize it and set it as the 
                 * cache for the new MSAL CCA instance. For more, see: 
                 * https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-node/docs/caching.md
                 */
                if (req.session.tokenCache) {
                    msalInstance.getTokenCache().deserialize(req.session.tokenCache);
                }

                const tokenResponse = await msalInstance.acquireTokenSilent({
                    account: req.session.account,
                    scopes: options.scopes || [],
                });

                /**
                 * On successful token acquisition, write the updated token 
                 * cache back to the session. For more, see: 
                 * https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-node/docs/caching.md
                 */
                req.session.tokenCache = msalInstance.getTokenCache().serialize();
                req.session.accessToken = tokenResponse.accessToken;
                req.session.idToken = tokenResponse.idToken;
                req.session.account = tokenResponse.account;

                res.redirect(options.successRedirect);
            } catch (error) {
                if (error instanceof msal.InteractionRequiredAuthError) {
                    return this.login({
                        scopes: options.scopes || [],
                        redirectUri: options.redirectUri,
                        successRedirect: options.successRedirect || '/',
                    })(req, res, next);
                }

                next(error);
            }
        };
    }

    handleRedirect(options = {}) {
        return async (req, res, next) => {
            if (!req.body || !req.body.state) {
                return next(new Error('Error: response not found'));
            }

            const authCodeRequest = {
                ...req.session.authCodeRequest,
                code: req.body.code,
                codeVerifier: req.session.pkceCodes.verifier,
            };

            try {
                const msalInstance = this.getMsalInstance(this.msalConfig);

                if (req.session.tokenCache) {
                    msalInstance.getTokenCache().deserialize(req.session.tokenCache);
                }

                const tokenResponse = await msalInstance.acquireTokenByCode(authCodeRequest, req.body);

                req.session.tokenCache = msalInstance.getTokenCache().serialize();
                req.session.idToken = tokenResponse.idToken;
                req.session.account = tokenResponse.account;
                req.session.isAuthenticated = true;

                const state = JSON.parse(this.cryptoProvider.base64Decode(req.body.state));
                res.redirect(state.successRedirect);
            } catch (error) {
                next(error);
            }
        }
    }

    logout(options = {}) {
        return (req, res, next) => {

            /**
             * Construct a logout URI and redirect the user to end the
             * session with Azure AD. For more information, visit:
             * https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-protocols-oidc#send-a-sign-out-request
             */
            let logoutUri = `${this.msalConfig.auth.authority}/oauth2/v2.0/`;

            if (options.postLogoutRedirectUri) {
                logoutUri += `logout?post_logout_redirect_uri=${options.postLogoutRedirectUri}`;
            }

            req.session.destroy(() => {
                res.redirect(logoutUri);
            });
        }
    }

    /**
     * Instantiates a new MSAL ConfidentialClientApplication object
     * @param msalConfig: MSAL Node Configuration object 
     * @returns 
     */
    getMsalInstance(msalConfig) {
        return new msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(msalConfig);
    }


    /**
     * Prepares the auth code request parameters and initiates the first leg of auth code flow
     * @param req: Express request object
     * @param res: Express response object
     * @param next: Express next function
     * @param authCodeUrlRequestParams: parameters for requesting an auth code url
     * @param authCodeRequestParams: parameters for requesting tokens using auth code
     */
    redirectToAuthCodeUrl(authCodeUrlRequestParams, authCodeRequestParams, msalInstance) {
        return async (req, res, next) => {
            // Generate PKCE Codes before starting the authorization flow
            const { verifier, challenge } = await this.cryptoProvider.generatePkceCodes();

            // Set generated PKCE codes and method as session vars
            req.session.pkceCodes = {
                challengeMethod: 'S256',
                verifier: verifier,
                challenge: challenge,
            };

            /**
             * By manipulating the request objects below before each request, we can obtain
             * auth artifacts with desired claims. For more information, visit:
             * https://azuread.github.io/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/ref/modules/_azure_msal_node.html#authorizationurlrequest
             * https://azuread.github.io/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/ref/modules/_azure_msal_node.html#authorizationcoderequest
             **/
            req.session.authCodeUrlRequest = {
                ...authCodeUrlRequestParams,
                responseMode: msal.ResponseMode.FORM_POST, // recommended for confidential clients
                codeChallenge: req.session.pkceCodes.challenge,
                codeChallengeMethod: req.session.pkceCodes.challengeMethod,
            };

            req.session.authCodeRequest = {
                ...authCodeRequestParams,
                code: '',
            };

            try {
                const authCodeUrlResponse = await msalInstance.getAuthCodeUrl(req.session.authCodeUrlRequest);
                res.redirect(authCodeUrlResponse);
            } catch (error) {
                next(error);
            }
        };
    }

    /**
     * Retrieves cloud discovery metadata from the /discovery/instance endpoint
     * @returns 
     */
    async getCloudDiscoveryMetadata(authority) {
        const endpoint = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/discovery/instance';

        try {
            const response = await axios.get(endpoint, {
                params: {
                    'api-version': '1.1',
                    'authorization_endpoint': `${authority}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize`
                }
            });

            return await response.data;
        } catch (error) {
            throw error;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Retrieves oidc metadata from the openid endpoint
     * @returns
     */
    async getAuthorityMetadata(authority) {
        const endpoint = `${authority}/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration`;

        try {
            const response = await axios.get(endpoint);
            return await response.data;
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }
}

const authProvider = new AuthProvider(msalConfig);

module.exports = authProvider;


I followed this MS Doc to create an Expressjs project.

Local implementation of MSAL-node in Express JS works fine but after deploying to remote Widows server it returns error 500 and there is nothing related in the server logs.

To avoid the above error, I deployed the application to an Azure Linux Web App.
Before deploying the project to Azure Web App, you need to replace the REDIRECT_URI and POST_LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URI in the .env.dev file.
.env.dev :
CLOUD_INSTANCE="https://login.microsoftonline.com/" 
TENANT_ID="<tenantID>"
CLIENT_ID="<clientID>"
CLIENT_SECRET="<clientSecret>"

REDIRECT_URI="AzureWebAppURL/auth/redirect"
POST_LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URI="AzureWebAppURL"

GRAPH_API_ENDPOINT="https://graph.microsoft.com/"
EXPRESS_SESSION_SECRET=""

I added the Azure web app URL to the Azure AD app's redirect URI under the Web section.
<AzureWebAppURL>/auth/redirect


Azure web app Output :




